# How to convert every second element in the list into int format?

Tags: python-3.x, list, printing

As mentioned in the title, I'm not sure if this variable "a" is python list format, but it contains the content is like this:

```
[[{'index': 1, 'lemma': 'PASADENA', 'speaker': 'PER0', 'word': 'PASADENA', 'originalText': 'PASADENA', 'characterOffsetEnd': 109, 'pos': 'NNP', 'after': '', 'before': ' ', 'ner': 'LOCATION', 'characterOffsetBegin': 101}, {'index': 2, 'lemma': ',', 'speaker': 'PER0', 'word': ',', 'originalText': ',', 'characterOffsetEnd': 110, 'pos': ',', 'after': ' ', 'before': '', 'ner': 'O', 'characterOffsetBegin': 109}, {'index': 3, 'lemma': 'Calif.', 'speaker': 'PER0', 'word': 'Calif.', 'originalText': 'Calif.', 'characterOffsetEnd': 117, 'pos': 'NNP', 'after': ' ', 'before': ' ', 'ner': 'LOCATION', 'characterOffsetBegin': 111}], 199274586, Point(34.1476452, -118.1444779, 0.0), [34.1172023, 34.251905, -118.198139, -118.065479], 182911336, 0, 0, <Giveme5W1H.extractor.candidate.Candidate object at 0x7f1199bcec50>, 0]
[[{'index': 13, 'lemma': 'Mars', 'speaker': 'PER0', 'word': 'Mars', 'originalText': 'Mars', 'characterOffsetEnd': 162, 'pos': 'NNP', 'after': '', 'before': ' ', 'ner': 'LOCATION', 'characterOffsetBegin': 158}], '198791424', Point(44.0009649, 3.5560447, 0.0), [43.9912494, 44.0146261, 3.535728, 3.5664698], 6390941, 0, 0, <Giveme5W1H.extractor.candidate.Candidate object at 0x7f1199bcec88>, 0]
[[{'index': 48, 'lemma': 'Mars', 'speaker': 'PER0', 'word': 'Mars', 'originalText': 'Mars', 'characterOffsetEnd': 362, 'pos': 'NNP', 'after': ' ', 'before': ' ', 'ner': 'LOCATION', 'characterOffsetBegin': 358}], '198791424', Point(44.0009649, 3.5560447, 0.0), [43.9912494, 44.0146261, 3.535728, 3.5664698], 6390941, 0, 0, <Giveme5W1H.extractor.candidate.Candidate object at 0x7f1199bcecc0>, 0]
[[{'index': 86, 'lemma': 'Mars', 'speaker': 'PER0', 'word': 'Mars', 'originalText': 'Mars', 'characterOffsetEnd': 551, 'pos': 'NNP', 'after': '', 'before': ' ', 'ner': 'LOCATION', 'characterOffsetBegin': 547}], '198791424', Point(44.0009649, 3.5560447, 0.0), [43.9912494, 44.0146261, 3.535728, 3.5664698], 6390941, 0, 0, <Giveme5W1H.extractor.candidate.Candidate object at 0x7f1199b8c9e8>, 0]
```

When I print the second element out it is like this.
[199274586, '198791424', '198791424', '198791424']
As you can see there're some of them are string, how can I convert them into integer format without changing its numeric value in variable 'a'? Thank you.

Comment: the input you provide contains functions and object adresses - it is therefore hard to reproduce what you actually want to do. Could you please clarify? (check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: What is variable 'a'? The 4 lines of code/output you have seem to be 4 separate lists. You're going to want to use `int()` or `float()`.